# Trying to use IF with MAX in MYSQL to get most recent date between 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got two tables (MySQL), one with a list of categories and another with a list of products which can be assigned to a category. I need to pull out the date of the most recent change across both tables so I can reset the cache for this page if needed.

I seem to be struggling with using MAX() in a CASE, currently I have this which works but the product date is just the latest one entered into the database and not necessarily the most recent.

```
SELECT c.pageid as caturl, p.updated as pup, c.updated as dup,

CASE WHEN p.updated > c.updated THEN p.updated ELSE c.updated END AS latest

FROM products p, categories c 

WHERE p.catid = c.id AND c.hide=0

GROUP BY c.title
```

When I try to use MAX() within the CASE it throws an error, as it does when using an IF.

I'd appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.  Do you want the most recently updated product for each category? Or do you want the most recently updated product and the most recently updated category?

Comment: I want the most recent of the two. the pup/dup fields are only in there for my reference.

Comment: It would be easier then just to do two queries and compare them in php.

Comment: @Julien, easier yes, also much much slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm taking a stab at this, two derived tables.

One, that calculate the MostRecent updated date for each category in the categories table: "catdates" (and also returns the pageid)

The Other, calculates the MostRecent updated date across all products in a given category for each category in the products table: "proddates"

Then we just join on categoryid and take the higher value.

```
SELECT c.pageid,
GREATEST(proddate.LastModified,catdates.LastModified) AS LastModified
from
(SELECT p.catid as catid,MAX(p.updated) AS LastModified
FROM products p
GROUP BY p.id,p.catid) proddates
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT c.id AS catid,c.pageid,MAX(c.updated) AS LastModified
FROM categories c
WHERE c.hide=0
GROUP BY c.id,c.pageid) catdates
ON proddates.catid=catdates.catid
```

Comment: @AI_ Feel free to further clarify the business logic and the way products/categories relate to each other if this doesn't quite do it.

Comment: Thanks, I made a couple of minor tweaks and it works great now:`SELECT DISTINCT(catdates.pageid),
GREATEST(proddates.LastModified,catdates.LastModified) AS LastModified
from
(SELECT p.catid as catid,MAX(p.updated) AS LastModified
FROM products p
GROUP BY p.id,p.catid) proddates
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT c.id AS catid,c.pageid,MAX(c.updated) AS LastModified
FROM categories c
WHERE c.hide=0
GROUP BY c.id,c.pageid) catdates
ON proddates.catid=catdates.catid`

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the latest rows, something like:

```
SELECT   
  c.pageid as caturl
  , p.updated as pup
  , c.updated as dup
  ,GREATEST(p.updated,c.updated) AS latest
FROM products p
INNER JOIN categories c ON (p.catid = c.id)
WHERE c.hide=0
GROUP BY caturl
HAVING lastest = MAX(lastest)
```

The `greatest` function negates the need for the `case when`, although it does not change the query.
The real change is in the `having` clause that selects only the latest rows.

Comment: Thanks, but the query returns only 3 out of a total 4 categories. All the categories have at least one product in, I can't see why it would do that. Removing the HAVING clause shows all the categories, but then it doesn't show the most recent date

Comment: I think the reason the query above isn't working is because of the two products in that category the one that MySQL returns by default (ie newest record in the database) was last updated (ie the date stored in the table itself) is before the 'updated' date in the other product. So it seems that query only pulls the newest record CREATED in the db, rather than which one has the most recent date field in it.

Comment: Then you need to group by caturl.